# Scope variables not inherited to child controllers from state parent controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I do this in Ionic Framework. It started in the `home.html` template with `eventmenu.home` state. The `$scope.aaa` variable is `10` and it shows that value correctly. However, in a child controller `TestCtrl` of that template, I cannot change the `$scope.aaa` value and gets it updated. **What's wrong with my method as why `aaa` did not get increased**? Is `TestCtrl` in a different scope than `HomeCtrl` although it should be the child of `HomeCtrl`, no?

CODE:

http://codepen.io/hawkphil/pen/xbmZGm

HTML:

```
<script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Welcome" >
        <ion-content class="padding" >
          <p>Swipe to the right to reveal the left menu.</p>
          <p>(On desktop click and drag from left to right)</p>
          <p>{{ aaa }}</p>
          <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
            <a ng-click="clickMe()" href="">Click Me</a>
          </div>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>
```

JS:

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.aaa = 10;
})

.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.clickMe = function() {
    $scope.aaa++;
  }
})
```

p.s I am using the code from somebody so please ignore other stuffs.

Comment: why not just use a service? Unless I am missing something here? Also this code you provided does not reflect the codepen you linked to

Comment: I could use service but that is not the question. My question is on the inheritance principle of $scope. See my p.s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an issue with Ionic, or with ui-router, or really even with Angular. It's just how javascript works.

You can see the same issues arise in plain Angular using `ng-if`. It has to do with *how* javascript inheritance works.

If the child scope doesn't have it's *own* `aaa` property it uses it's parent. But once you click the button, you make it's *own* property, one more than the parent's was. But now they are separate properties, the parent's `aaa` and the child's `aaa`.

### Example

You can see a pure javascript example here...
[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbZWRe). Click the `Inc Parent` as much as you like, both the parent and child displays are incremented. Clicking the `Inc Child` breaks the connection. Once the connection is broken you can "unhide" the parent value by deleting the child's property by clicking the `Unhide` button.

**code**

```
var obj = function () {}
obj.aaa = 10
obj.inc = function () {
  this.aaa += 1;
};

var objB = function () {};
objB.__proto__ = obj; // Make objB a child of obj
objB.inc = function () {
  this.aaa += 1;
};
objB.unhide = function () {
  delete this.aaa;
};

var update = function () {
  document.getElementById("p").textContent = obj.aaa;
  document.getElementById("c").textContent = objB.aaa;
};
update();
```

**html**

```
<button onclick="obj.inc(); update();">Inc Parent</button>
<button onclick="objB.inc();  update();">Inc Child</button>
<button onclick="objB.unhide();  update();">Unhide</button>

<p>
  Parent's value: <span id="p"></p>
</p>
<p>
  Child's value: <span id="c"></p>
</p>
```

Comment: I understand this logic but I didn't get why Angular don't automatically reuse the parent variable instead. I decided to post a separate question on this on how to fix this logic in angular app. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160182/sync-child-scope-var-with-parent-var

Comment: @HP. - Why should they change anything? This is the expected behavior in javascript. Changing the way it behaves would make a lot of javascript programmers wonder what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Every controller has its own `$scope` object. Child controllers can access their parents using `$parent`:

```
.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.clickMe = function() {
        $scope.$parent.aaa++;
    }
})
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNOEpq)

Comment: But by principle, the scope vars are inherited from the parents. Why not in this case? What I did different?

Comment: This is how to fix the problem, but its not an explanation of what the problem is.